# How to redirect whole domain to a single Wordpress page with Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a Wordpress website, installed on `domain1.com`, where I need to redirect all `domain2.com` traffic to a `domain1.com/somepage` page.

I have an http-to-https redirect in place (automatic from certbot) and the default wordpress nginx configuration, and everything works fine with a domain mapping plugin: `https://domain2.com`correctly shows `https://domain1.com/somepage` keeping the original url.

The problem is that `https://domain2.com/somethingelse` should always redirect to `https://domain1.com/somepage`, as of now it redirects to the Wordpress 404 page (which is on `domain1.com`.

I've tried fiddling with redirects and rewrites in nginx, the best result was a redirection loop:

```
if ($host = domain2.com){
  rewrite ^/(.+)$ / last;
}
```

How can I achieve full domain redirection?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using another Wordpress plugin: [Redirection](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).

I just set a redirect for `/.+` matching the `Host:domain2.com` header to `https://domain2.com`.

[Multiple domain mapping](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain-mapping-on-single-site/) plugin takes care of mapping `domain2.com` to the correct page.